# Android application label changes

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm tearing my hair out over this one.  I've got an application for which I use a short title to display in the launcher etc.  I've also got a longer string that I use to display at the top of the screen from within the app (where there is more space).  The observant will note that I do try to set NoTitleBar but not all devices appear to obey this style, which is why the long title must remain.

The problem I am having is that the label used on the app icon in the laucnher & desktop seemingly randomly reverts to the long string on some devices.  On other devices everything is fine.  I can't determine whether there are some artifacts lingering from an old version of the app, if its something I am doing wrong or if it's a bug with certain devices.  The fact that its happening across multiple devices/vendors makes me tend to doubt the later.

My AndroidManifest consists of the standard stuff; an application tag containing a variety of activities.  For reasons I dont understand, I was able to fix the problem on some devices by adding an android:label to all my IntentFilters.

This is basically what my AndroidManifest looks like:

```
    <application android:label="@string/global_app_short_name" android:icon="@drawable/app">
            <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"                  
                      android:launchMode="singleTask"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A1"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A2"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A3"
                      android:launchMode="singleTask"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A4"
                      android:launchMode="singleTask"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A5"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A6"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <activity android:name=".A7"
                      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
                <intent-filter android:label="@string/global_app_short_name">
                 ...some stuff...
                </intent-filter>

            </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: just define, android:label for application tag for Application label, and for activity tag for screen(Not in filter).

Comment: Thats what I started with and where the problem began.  I added the label to filter based on comments others had made in similar threads.  It seems to fix the issue on most devices but not all :(

Comment: you should, your device name, which replicating different senario for same thing, that will make easy to catch your problem..